# Linq implementation of for and if loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops

This snippet below checks if `eCode` (an integer) is equal to any element in `list1<int>` and if yes, it does something. My question is the following.. what would be a linq implementation of this? I'm new to C# and Linq and not sure how to proceed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (list1[i] == eCode)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't for creating side effects, it's for filtering out data. If you want to change anything inside your `if` condition, you shouldn't be using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is effectively the same as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30898002/76337) from [Stephen Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397817/stephen-kennedy), but I sometimes like this syntax. Usually for more complicated things, but still:

```
foreach (var item in from l in list1
                     where l == eCode
                     select l)
{
    // Do something with each item
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can retain the loop but convert the conditional statement into a LINQ `Where` clause:

```
foreach (var item in list1.Where(l => l == eCode))
{
    // Do something with each item
}
```

Comment: Right, but we already know that the items are `int`s, so the equality checks are trivial. What seems to be important are the indices of items that match `eCode`, and you can't do anything interesting with these indices using pure LINQ.

Comment: He's not looking at the indeces, he's using the index to get the value and then compare it - unless I'm misreading the code posted which is entirely possible! list1[i] returns the value of that list item.

Comment: Ah well maybe I was reading too much into the use of a `for` loop and then the index `i`. I was thinking, "if the index didn't matter, then this would just be a `foreach` loop, so therefore the index *must* matter!". However, of course, it could simply be that the asker didn't know of a better way. I'm sure you're right, and so I upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I think the below snippet is what you are looking for:

```
List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int eCode = 3;
bool result = i.Any(x => x == eCode);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is using the LINQ extension methods, not actual LINQ.

```
if (list1.Any(i => i == eCode))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This works if the requirement is that at least one item fits the criteria, but the loop in the question technically runs `do something` on every match.